# Excel formula to compare the 2 columns and extract the value from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Help me with the excel formula based on the below logic:

I need to populate the value in Column D as shown in the below table:

Currently I am having values till Column C

```
Header        Column A   Column B   Column C       Column D
Row 2          Raj         AAA        AAA(NEW)      Vinay
Row 3          Vinay                  AAA           Vinay
Row 4          Kumar                  BBB           Kumar
Row 5          Arun                   CCC           Arun
Row 6          Ajay        DDD        DDD(NEW)      Rahul  
Row 7          Rahul                  DDD           Rahul
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following formula in `D1` cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$7,0)),A2)
```

[image]

Comment: the formula does not work for the above updated question, please help

Comment: Then use table name as `Index()` function array and use column name as `match()` function array. better if you can attach a sample file via google drive and put link here

Comment: In that case just you need to adjust the ranges. See the updated answer. If you have data like 10,000 rows then use formula like `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10000,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$10000,0)),A2)`

Comment: Sir, please dont consider the number of rows are fixed, I m having N number of rows

Comment: the number of rows is not fixed it keeps on changing

Comment: please help how to apply the formula if u don't know the number of rows

Comment: There no infinity rows in excel. So, why it would be unknow? Maximum row number is in excel 2013 is `1048576` So, use `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1048576,MATCH(B2,$C$2:$C$1048576,0)),A2)`

Comment: Suppose you have data till row-5000 and you will insert more data later. Then use 25000 to formula so that if data increases it will not cause any issue.

Comment: thanx harun, it solved the problem, I am not aware of excel formulas, so couldn't get it first time..

Comment: Glad it works! No issue have some time and research on formulas if you use excel regularly.

Comment: Hey Harun24H I am not getting the above result using the formula which u shared ,, please help...In the second row, instead of Arun I am getting kumar, please help..

@Harun24H  Harun24H

Comment: below is the image of excel in  "enter image description here"  Harun24HR